# python import .mat file: how to just import one wanted column from a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray, mat-file

I have this .mat file D887_ALL.mat and there are several matrices in it, one is called trigger_events and is a 671×2 matrix. I will only use the first column. Can I just import the first column in Python?

This is what I can do now, just import the whole matrix events:

```
dataFile='/Users/gaoyingqiang/Desktop/Python/D887_All.mat'
data=scio.loadmat(dataFile)
trigger_events=['trigger_events']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you've a typo in the 3rd line

Comment: Do the column selection after loading.  `loadmat` doesn't give any further controls, does it?

Comment: [Please consider accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped, else let me know the issue!

Answer (score 1):

How about this if you want just the first column?

```
trigger_events_col1 = data['trigger_events'][:, 1]
```